# Considering special cases in general definitions

Tags: function-construction

I want to calculate some coefficients

$\qquad B_k = 2\int_0^1 u(x) \cos(k\pi x)\,dx$

for $0<k\in\mathbb N$
and I am doing this in the following way:

```
Subscript[B, k_] = 
  FullSimplify[2 Integrate[u[x] Cos[k π x], {x, 0, 1}], {k ∈ Integers, k > 0}]
```

where `u[x_]` is defined earlier. While this works fine if `u` is e.g. a polynomial, it will fail, when `u` is of the form

```
u[x_] = Cos[3 π x]
```

Analytically I know that $B_k=0$ except for $B_3=1$. How can I tell *Mathematica* not to drop the special case?

I know that the workaround

```
Subscript[B, 3] = FullSimplify[2 Integrate[u[x] Cos[3 π x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

before the general definition will fix my problem, but I want it to work correctly for any `u`.

Comment: Have you seen `FourierCosCoefficient[]`?

Comment: No haven't yet. It seems to do what I try to achieve, when I set `FourierParameters -> {1,\[Pi]}`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $cos(2 \pi k x)$ considering your limits?

Comment: No, I am sure about that :)

Comment: @Wauzl So if `u[x]=Sin[2 Pi x]` your $B_1$ is not zero. Is that OK?

Comment: If you instead use the assumption that `k` is real (preferably inside `Integrate`) then the result should be such that one can take `Limit` at any given integer and get a correct result. Here is what I have in mind:  `In[2653]:= u[x_] := Cos[3 *Pi* x]
bk = Integrate[u[x]*Cos[k*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]]

Out[2654]= (k Sin[k \[Pi]])/(9 \[Pi] - k^2 \[Pi])`

Comment: @BlacKow: Yes, really I am sure about that, even if it may look a little strange to you. @DanielLichtblau: This does not really help, since I would get something indeterminate for `k=3`. @JM: Maybe your Comment should be an answer since it handles `k=3` correctly.